# Accessing a local variable from a function in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, variables

I have 2 javascript files, main.js, and  array.js. In main.js, I hold my main javascript, but in array.js, I have an object, mainObj, too large to have in my main.js because of lagging. In mainObj, some of the properties are getting a random value from a variable, myVar, like this

```
 "1": myVar[Object.keys(myVar. 
 [Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.keys(myVar).length)]]
```

When the website loads, it gets that random value 1 time, when the website loads, but I need it to get a random value every time I press a button.

The only way that I can get this to work is by making mainObj local to the function that is activated when I press a button. That function, giveOutput() is in main.js. But as I said before, having mainObj in main.js causes crashing. I have tried making mainObj global in array.js, then calling it in a function, showObject(), that is in array.js.

```
var mainObj;

function showObject() {
      mainObj = {
                  "1":myVar[Object.keys(myVar[Math.floor(Math.random()*Object.keys(myVar).length)]],
                  "2": "Content"
                   //The array goes on like this for a while
                }
}
```

Then I call it in giveOutput().

```
function giveOutput() {
      var output = mainObj;
}
```

But I always get an error "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'mainObj')"

I want to be able to access mainObj from giveOutput() in main.js, as opposed to getting an error.

Comment: Do you have any server-side processing (ASP.NET / PHP etc) or is it just pure HTML + JS? "causes crashing" - what type of crashing do you mean? Browser crashing or JS error?

Comment: The main file is index.php, and uses php include,  but other than that, pure HTML and JS

Comment: The web page isn't crashing, its my text editor because the file is a 5mb array/object

Comment: The most obvious solution which comes to my mind is to make your `array.js` a JSON file, like `array.json`, and just load it from `main.js`. Then, you don't need to actually store it this way, but it still unclear what kind of "crashing" problem do you have with JS solution.

Comment: Since you have PHP, you can also define all your 5 MB values in PHP and make a PHP page which will return a random value each time, so that client doesn't need to take care of it itself :)

Comment: At some point I was trying to use .json, but I had some javascript in the array, so it didn't work in .json

Comment: And I have't the slightest clue about how to make a huge array in php, and not every single one of the values is random, some of them are set, and don't get changed